# Makefile, Regex and multiple dependencies

Tags: gnu-make

Assume the following files are in the same directory as the makefile:

```
01.1.dot
01.2.dot
02.1.dot
03.1.dot
03.2.dot
03.3.dot
```

That means we have files of the form [0-9][0-9].[0-9].dot

Furthermore, the makefile contains the following target:

```
%.dot.tex: %.dot
    dot2tex <...>
```

Now I would like to create a target which depend on files of the form [0-9][0-9].tex and they should also depend on all files of the form [0-9][0-9].*.dot.tex, such that the first two digits match. For example, `make 03.pdf` should depend on `03.tex`, `03.1.dot.tex`, `03.2.dot.tex` and `03.3.dot.tex`. I came up with the following:

```
%.pdf: %.tex $(addsuffix .tex,$(wildcard %.*.dot))
        @echo $?
        pdflatex <...>
```

However, the percentage is not evaluated in the wildcard-function. Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Functions are applied before pattern matching rules, so you cannot use % in a glob.

There is probably a better solution, but I came up with:

```
.dep-%.pdf: %.tex
    @bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; for x in $*.*.dot; do \
      echo "$*.pdf: $$x.tex"; \
    done' > $@
PDFS := $(patsubst %.tex,%.pdf,$(wildcard [0-9][0-9].tex))
include $(patsubst %,.dep-%,$(PDFS))
%.pdf: %.tex | .dep-%.pdf
```

As long as you don't add or create X.*.dot files without also modifying X.tex files, this should work.